# clientservice server response format

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google scripts and I am trying to get a couple of google sites gadgets to communicate with each other.

I believe the following code (based on google's ClientService examples) should work.

Gadget1 Client:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("ClientService Client test");
    app.setStyleAttribute("background", "azure");

    var options =
    {
          "method" : "get",
          "v1" : "value for field one"
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyIa07kBC-gqG0nJq3Up5GzUntbTaYcM1KmaYF7vQvFIWN_qxA/exec", options);

    var lbl = app.createHTML(response.getContentText());
//  var lbl = app.createTextArea().setText(response.getContentText());

    app.add(lbl);
    return app;
}
```

Gadget2 server:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var v1 = e.parameters.v1;

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Hi from ClientServer : " + v1);
}
```

I have embedded the client in google sites.
The server is deployed so anyone/anon can access it.

After the client gadget loads, I dont see anything in the client HTML widget. Dumping the response in a TextArea seems show some raw html even that says 'ReferenceError: "request" not defined'

I believe I am missing something trivial for more than 4 hours now... any quick gotchas??